# How to add class to elements containing blacklist words

Tags: javascript, regex, blacklist

I want to add a class to HTML elements whichever contains one of the blacklist words.

For example, my blacklist consists of "bad" and "ugly", I want to add class to their span:

```
<div id="main">
    <span>This is good.</span>
    <span class="black">Bad things happen sometimes.</span>
    <span class="black">This is bad.</span>
    <span class="black">And this is ugly.</span>
</div>

<a onclick="blacklisterFunction();">Add Class</a>
```

How the blacklisterFunction() should look like? Should the function crawl the main div for each of blacklisted word or is there a more effective way.

Comment: U need a span class to those words or the sentence?

Comment: The whole sentence will be styled for one bad word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
function blacklister(el, words) {
    if (!el || !words) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var text = el.textContent;
        for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (text.test(new RegExp(words[i],'gi'))) {
                el.className += 'black';
            }
        }
    }
}

var m = document.getElementById('main'),
    spans = m.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    blacklist = ['ugly','bad'];

for (var i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; i++) {
    blacklister(spans[i],blacklist);
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ydDee/).

---

**Edited** in response to comment left by OP, below, reporting errors using the above in Firefox:

>

```
function blacklister(el, words) {
    if (!el || !words) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var text = el.textContent;
        for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (text.match(new RegExp(words[i],'gi'))) {
                if (el.className.indexOf('black') == -1){
                    el.className += 'black';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var m = document.getElementById('main'),
    spans = m.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    blacklist = ['ugly','bad'];

for (var i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; i++) {
    blacklister(spans[i],blacklist);
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ydDee/1/).

References:

- [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).
- [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).
- [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent).

Comment: Is this dependent on Mootools? Firebug says "text.test is not a function" without Mootools.

Comment: No; it's native JavaScript. Though it might depend on the browser you're using; I used Chromium 18/Ubuntu 11.04. What're you using?

Comment: How about this [updated demo, using `match()` instead](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ydDee/1/)?

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
$('#clickme').click(function () {

    $('div span').each(function() {

        var badthings = ['bad', 'ugly', 'gross'];

        var x = 0;

        while (x <= (badthings.length - 1)) { 

            if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(badthings[x]) !== -1) {

                $(this).addClass('black');

            }

            x++;

        }

    });

});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DgpnQ/4/

Comment: Given that there's no [tag:jquery] tag, you might want to clarify that the jQuery library is required for this approach.